# How to add more light in dark room with realistic way?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, lighting

I trying to create room with sun light from the street. But when I'm doing this my room becoming too dark:
[image: Dark room]

I can add more light using additional light source but in that case lighting become not realistic:
[image: Light room]

Is that any way to leave only one light source but make it calculate more rays or something else to make my room more bright?

P.S. I won't render roof, it's only need to block the light.

Glass material:
[image: Glass material]

Comment: Light Portals are something to look into, I'm not sure how well they work, though, honestly

Comment: @AllenSimpson i've heard about it, but it's using only for denoising, isn't it?

Comment: I assume you've tried making the sun brighter?

Comment: @MartyFouts Of course, in that case "shadow" on the floor becomes brighter and that's all. It's practically doesn't affect on other room parts.

Comment: Is that some kind of glass material in the window or is it just openings?  You might want to take a look at Max Bounce settings in render properties under light paths; because it sounds like you might need to increase maybe diffuse or glossy.

Comment: @MartyFouts added glass material

Comment: I didn't mean that you should, but that's a good glass for your purpose.  What about the render settings for max bounce?

Comment: @MartyFouts Well, it was 12 and I change it to 1000 and nothing changed.